# Mod Rewrite - Check for a file in a particular directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm using the following mod rewrite script, I want to change it to try looking for a file in a particular directory, can somebody give me a hint on how to achieve this please?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rewrite needs to check if the filename exists in the requested location, then if that fails it will check in directory like '/themes/theme1', and finally it will go to /index.php when the above two fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check to see if a directory exists, use:

```
RewriteCond /path/to/directory -d
```

For a file, use

```
RewriteCond /path/to/file -f
```

Comment: Hi tylerl, how do I add the requested filename to the end of those RewriteCond statements?  And how do I write the rewrite rule to rewrite the location of the file?  Example request: /path/to/directory/css/styles.css

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the RewriteRule instead and it works RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ path/to/directory%{REQUEST_URI} [L]